# Mozilla Add on trying to login to a Rails application that uses Devise

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a Rails application that uses Devise for user authentication. I am developing an add-on and using ajax I make a post to my sign in route sending username and password (user[email] and user[password]) parameters.

I am trying to make a post to the xml route (users/sign_in.xml) so I get a XML response. Rails server works ok and creates the session.

I execute that from ajax and It returns success. After that if I try to execute another service that requires authentication, it returns an error that says that I am not logged in. Maybe I have to store a cookie or send a cookie in the next calls to Rails server.

From content script I am calling:

```
function signInSubmit(){
    var email = $('#sign_in_email').val();
    var password = $('#sign_in_password').val();
    signIn(email, password);
}

function signIn(email, password){
    var sign_in_data = {
        'user[email]' : email,
        "user[password]" : password
    }
    var params = EncodeQueryData(sign_in_data);
    invoke("/users/sign_in", params, signInCallBack);
}

function invoke(url_method, parameters, callback){
    var url = url_api + url_method + ".xml?" + parameters;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    type = 'POST';

    req.open("POST", url, true);
    req.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                callback(req.responseXML);
            }else if(req.status == 201){ 
                callback(req.responseXML);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}

function signInCallBack(doc){
    //This returns an XML saying that authentication was successfull.  
    // Session was created in the server
    login_session_key = doc.getElementsByTagName("email")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    callMethodThatNeedsAuthentication();
}


function callMethodThatNeedsAuthentication(){
    // This method call returns a not authenticated error.
    invoke("/api/methodthatneedsauthentication", "", NeedsAuthenticationCallBack);
}
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You're right - if you need to establish and use a session with your rails app from SDK code, and maintain the session by passing back whatever cookie data is set by the rails app.

I don't know how Rails session work, but what you will probably need to do is capture the session cookie used by rails and re-send it with subsequent requests. I don't think the Request module will allow you to manipulate cookies to do this ( see this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=741156 ) however I do know that with PHP you can instead supply the session key as a request parameter.

Comment: How can I use a session from SDK code?
Remember that I am in the content script of a FireFox Add On

Comment: @Tony: The fact that you use a content script (and `XMLHttpRequest` I guess) belongs into the question - please edit it to explain how you are logging in exactly.

Comment: It just seems to me like, if you have any control over the rails app at all, you would implement REST/JSON service in the rails app and implement a client based on that.

Comment: I have control over the rails app. The problem is that it uses Devise for authentication, which is cookie based. Any idea?

Comment: From the devise github ( https://github.com/plataformatec/devise ): "Token Authenticatable: signs in a user based on an authentication token (also known as "single access token"). The token can be given both through query string or HTTP Basic Authentication." ...it seems like you can authenticate using tokens as a request parameter.